# What is the simplest way to convert a string to a stream?

Tags: c#, string, stream

Today, I use a memory stream :

```
new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str))
```

Is there a simpler / better way ?

Thank you !

Comment: Looks good to me. What's the problem with this approach in your opinion that prompted this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That'll do it; there not really anything more direct than that, since you need the bytes (for the `Stream` API), hence need to go via an `Encoding`.

Note, however, that many APIs that take text-based data via a `Stream` will *also* accept a `TextReader`, and thus `new StringReader(str)` will be more direct.

Answer (score 2):

Try `System.IO.StringReader` class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there is simplest way or not, but I would say *there is no better way* (from the point of view of this question) to do this, as converting in memory, somehow you will need to convert it back. You need to know encodinig of the data you operate on.

In short: this is my prefered choice.